# Correct way of adding Facebook login to the Website

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I want to add Facebook login to my website, My script is working fine but I am not sure this way is correct or not, can you someone verify and suggest If I am doing wrong. And I have few questions.

Script:

```
  function statusChangeCallback(response) 
  {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      console.log('still not authorized!');
    } else {
      console.log("not connected, not logged into facebook, we don't know");
    }
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APP_ID',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    checkLoginState();
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

   function checkLoginState() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
   }

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', { fields: 'name,email,gender' }, function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
      window.location.replace('http://www.example.com');
    });
  }
```

Button display:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-onlogin="checkLoginState()" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-login-text="Sign in with Facebook"></div>
```

1. After successful login, I want to redirect to members-only.php by passing id, email. In the above script I have written window.location.replace('http://www.example.com'); instead example.com, can i give my php file name?
2. appId can be seen by every body, will that be fine? or we need to keep it as secret?
3. If the user is coming for the first time, what details we need to register in our database? and from second time how can we identify that user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not handle this client-side only - use the PHP SDK for the server-side part, it works together with the JS SDK (via shared cookies.)

Comment: So..we will get id, email and other details if needed and pass them to the backend and store if user is coming for the first time or if he/she is returning user verify the id in our database and redirect to members-only.php ? we only verify id? form the returning users?  Sorry for many questions, first time I am implementing fb login, thanks for your help.

Comment: Send only the access token to the server, request any additional info from there. Store the app-scoped user id in your database (VARCHAR or similar data type.)

Comment: So after login, we need to get only access_token and send it back to my server and using that access_token get id,email and other details of the user and save them into the database if its first time user, or if its returning user we need to verify that id and move forward? is that you are suggesting?  If so, my question is we can also get id along with the access_token in FB.api('/me'..call.  Why we need to use access_token then?

Comment: And you think FB.api works without an access token ...? Of course not. But any value you send from the client to the server could be manipulated - therefor you do not want to trust a user id, email, etc. sent from the client in the first place. The access token is a cryptic value that can't be guessed, so that is safe to send.

Comment: yes I am able to get id, email, and other details without the access token, can you check the above code testAPI() function. After login, I am able to get all those details.

Comment: No, that's because FB.api passes the access token for you automatically ...

Comment: Got you, so I will pass the access_token to my server and there I will make other FB graph api call to get the id and email, other stuff form the user. One last question, are we doing all this mainly for id and email only?

Answer (score 0):

1. `window.location.replace('http://www.example.com/members-only.php');`
2. It is no problem to make the App ID public. Just be careful with Access Tokens and the App Secret. They are not meant to be public.
3. You only need the ID to identify the user. The rest is up to you, if you want to cache it.

Comment: How can I pass id to the members-only.php? will that be any ajax call? Lets say ID is enough to identify the user from the second time, If I know my friends id I can easily pass that and call members-only.php and get his details ? is that secure?

Comment: in the members-only.php file, you have to check if the user is authorized. for example, you can pass the access token after login to an ajax call and store the token in a session. then just redirect to members-only.php and in there see if there is a token in the session and try to use it with the api (a simple call to the /me endpoint, for example). it is only secure if you check for the correct user server side, of course.

Comment: so we will use access_token for getting id? of course email and other details also.  Generally, we will use id for identifying the users.  This seems we are doing all this mess only for id, email mainly. I am correct? if so, we  can get id of any my facebook user in a less than a minute, then where is the security?

Comment: yes. use the token to get data, use/store the id to identify users. you cannot get anything without the access token, and you cannot get any data of users who did not authorize your app. keep the token secret and you will be fine. not sure what the security issue is?

Comment: I understood, but first time when user logged in I will get all the required data like id, email, profile pic, other stuff, then why I need to store the access token? instead of access token, why don't we store some flag to identify whether user is logged in or not.

Comment: who said that you need to store the access token? transfer it to the server, use the graph api on the server to get the user data, forget about the access token again.

Comment: Got you, thanks for your help luschn. I have verified your blog devils-heaven.com, that's also helped me.